# Box around raggedright links spanning two lines extends to right margin

Tags: horizontal-alignment, hyperref, line-breaking, links

I need to use boxed links and ragged right text. The problem is that when a link spans two lines, though the link is broken correctly (when using pdflatex) the box around the linked text extends until the right margin. Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=45mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\raggedright
\href{http://www.ctan.org/}{The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network}
\end{document}
```

In the output, the link box extends beyond the end of 'TeX' and up to the right margin, thus enclosing some white space. Is there a way to make the box around the link extend only up to the end of the text and not the right margin?

Comment: Related: [Adjust box around hyperref footnote links](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43900) (Compiling with XeLaTeX actually solves your problem, too.)

Comment: Manual way: `\href{http://www.ctan.org/}{The Comprehensive TeX} \href{http://www.ctan.org/}{Archive Network}`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: both solutions indeed work, but I was looking for a solution which works a) automatically and b) in pdflatex.

Answer (score 5):

Simplest is just to link each word separately. Probably if necessary one could prevent the acrobat link boxes from drawing the vertical lines between words, but perhaps this is enough?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=45mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\let\oldhref\href
\def\href#1#2{%
\def\hrlink{\oldhref{#1}}%
\hrrsp#2 \relax}

\def\hrrsp#1 #2{%
\hrlink{#1}%
\ifx\relax#2%
\expandafter\@gobbletwo
\else
\ %
\fi
\hrrsp#2}
\begin{document}
\raggedright
\href{http://www.ctan.org/}{The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network}
\end{document}
```