# Two references to the same footnote

Tags: hyperref, footnotes

I want to have two references to the same footnote.
My version has the problem that the reference to the footnote is represented with a uppercase number and I want it the same size as the footnote-number:

```
TextA~\footnote{TextFootnote\label{ftn:X}} 
TExtB~\ref{ftn:X}
```

Someone has a different solution?

whole document:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{Thesis}
\usepackage[english,german]{babel} 
\usepackage[textsize=tiny]{todonotes}
\usepackage{doi}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{acronym}  
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\setlist{nolistsep} 
\graphicspath{{Pictures/}{Figures/}}

\begin{document}
TextA~\footnote{TextFootnote\label{ftn:X}} \\
TextB~\textsuperscript{\ref{ftn:X}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `\textsuperscript{\ref{ftn:X}}`?

Comment: it worked but the linkborder is smaller.

Comment: You're using `hyperref` then? Please post a minimal working example starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` which shows the problem.

Comment: added info in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the footnote number as superscript use `\textsuperscript{\ref{<label>}}`. The link box provided by `hyperref` is not easy to tweak with, but in [Adjust box around hyperref footnote links](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43900/adjust-box-around-hyperref-footnote-links) there is a [solution to make all boxes fit the number tightly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45656/81905).

Resulting in:

[image]

## MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%% Code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45656/81905
\usepackage{ltxcmds}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\footnote}[2][\empty]{%
  \nolinebreak%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{+1}%
  \xdef\sfootnote@number{\arabic{footnote}}%
  \ltx@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{% hyperref loaded
    \ifHy@hyperfootnotes% option hyperfootnotes=true
      \addtocounter{Hfootnote}{+1}%
      % Code from the hyperref package
        \global\let\Hy@saved@currentHref\@currentHref%
        \hyper@makecurrent{Hfootnote}%
        \global\let\Hy@footnote@currentHref\@currentHref%
        \global\let\@currentHref\Hy@saved@currentHref%
      % End of code form the hyperref package
    \fi%
   }{% hyperref not loaded, nothing to be done here
   }%
  \xdef\sfootnote@opt{#1}% contains the optional argument
  \xdef\sfootnote@arabic{\arabic{footnote}}% is the Arabic footnotenumber
  \edef\sfootnote@formated{\thefootnote}% could also be * or dagger
  \ifx\sfootnote@opt\empty% i.e. no optional argument used
    \footnotetext{\label{fnr:\sfootnote@arabic}#2}%
  \else%
    \ltx@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{% hyperref loaded
      \footnotetext[#1]{\phantomsection\label{fnr:\sfootnote@arabic}#2}%
     }{% hyperref not loaded
      \footnotetext[#1]{\label{fnr:\sfootnote@arabic}#2}%
     }%
  \fi%
  \ltx@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{% hyperref package loaded
    \ifHy@hyperfootnotes% option hyperfootnotes=true
      \hbox {\@textsuperscript {\normalfont \ref{fnr:\sfootnote@arabic}}}%
    \else% option hyperfootnotes=false
      \hbox {\@textsuperscript {\normalfont \ref*{fnr:\sfootnote@arabic}}}%
    \fi%
  }{% hyperref package not loaded
    \hbox {\@textsuperscript {\normalfont \ref{fnr:\sfootnote@arabic}}}%
   }%
}
\makeatother
%% End of code

\begin{document}
\noindent Textoç~\footnote{TextFootnote\label{ftn:X}} \\
TextB~\textsuperscript{\ref{ftn:X}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: if i use this all my footnotes `~\footnote{blabla}` become question marks.

Comment: Did you compile your code more than once?

Comment: Clear, I didn't. Now the right numbers appears with resized borders. But when i click: some bring me to the beginning of the document, some bring me to wrong footnotes and other bring me to the right place.

Comment: That seems to be another (very likely unrelated) problem. Please put together another MWE that shows this problem and ask another question. `:)`

Comment: But when I don't use your version, the clicking of the numbers bring me to the right footnote.

Comment: Ok, that's very odd then. Which part? the tighen boxing or just the `\textsuperscript`? Because for me it's working just fine... Can you add a MWE where this problem happens??

Comment: @marsUbuntux please, try deleting the `document.aux` and `document.out` files from your folder after you activate this tweak, and compile **3** times. Does the problem persist?

Comment: @yo' the problem persist. Should i delete the .aux and .out file every time i compile?

Comment: @GuilhermeZanotelli I have a big document (my thesis) and i don't know what to post here to reproduce this error. I am using a template that has been adopted, so i don't really know the whole structure plus i am not a expert at latex.

Comment: @marsUbuntux, of course posting your whole code wouldn't be a good idea. Though the process of making a MWE that can reprodruce the problem is something that needs to be done for us to troublehoot the problem. Maybe it's an incompatibility between packages... Did you load `hyperreff` as the last package? Try removing packages that mess with the footnotes or packages that could be related.

Comment: now it is working! I don't know why. Maybe i delete an old package that i never used. Thank you for the help. I will mark this answer as solution.

Comment: Good then. It's like a said, the making of a minimum document which still shows the problem sometimes already solves said problem. `=D`